# How to draw separate pixels efficiently on canvas context?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

The canvas context can draw pixels with strokes (moveTo, lineTo), and you can basically make it 1 pixel long. Though now I have to do two actions for 1, it seems. Plus, I'd want to basically pre-create my own pixel image.

As an example, let's say we want to create the following image:

[image: random pixel distribution]

20x20. To create this, I'd want to do the following to a 20x20 pixel space: assign (row, column); (0, 0), (0, 17), (1, 9), etc. (until 19.19) as white. The rest will be defaulted as another chosen color (or as the canvas background); black.

I'd want to create a loop, or put in a predetermined formula or a random algorithm to assign to the pixels. Basically, pass in some function to run, or pixels to assign (with a width and height) into the *"'create pixel image' function"*, to create an image which I can put in the context and display on the canvas. As a bonus I could also translate, rotate, skew, etc. this Image, since I have full control.

Comment: Good for you assuming I didn't

Comment: No code in the question ... we all assume there was no attempt

Comment: I can give you code to draw one pixel with the mentioned moveTo, lineTo.. Not sure what you expect. I just need some help getting an efficient way of drawing a pixel on the context, and alternatively for people who actually want to help, some advice on setting up the function. But thanks for your input, very valuable

Comment: Yes add some code to your question, when I read the title: `How to draw separate pixels efficiently on canvas context?` I was thinking that you have all the drawing all done, but your implementation was slow ... but looking at the content of the question (no code) it looks like there has been no attempt on your part, and the title was just "click bait" ... questions like this get downvoted and close all the time, my recommendation read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Get your CanvasElement context using [.getContext("2d")](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D)
- create a function (`drawRect`) that basically creates a rectangle of *size* at `x`, `y` coordinates inside your canvas
- Create an array of the arguments-Array `x, y, w, h, color` to be passed to your function
- Loop your array calling the `drawRect` function with the given arguments

```js
const drawRect = (ctx, x, y, w=1, h=1, color="#fff") => {
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
};


const size = 20;
const ctx = document.querySelector("#cvs").getContext("2d");

ctx.canvas.width = size;
ctx.canvas.height = size;

const myPixels = [
  [8, 5],
  [6, 18],
  [10, 10],
  [15, 13, 2, 2, "fuchsia"], // [x, y, w, h, color]
];

// 1. Draw black background
drawRect(ctx, 0, 0, size, size, "#000");

// 2. Draw individual whites
myPixels.forEach(args => drawRect(ctx, ...args));
```

```css
canvas {
  image-rendering: pixelated;
  width: 10em;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="cvs"></canvas>
```

so by using the above you can also create a bigger square pixel using i.e: `[10, 10, 3, 3, "#fb0"]` instead of `[10, 10]` (which is by default a single white pixel)

---

The above is just a functional approach of the following basic example:

```js
const ctx = document.querySelector("#cvs").getContext("2d");

ctx.canvas.width = 20;
ctx.canvas.height = 20;

// 1. Color all black
ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

// 2. Color white pixels individually:
const myPixels = [
  [8, 5],
  [6, 18],
  [10, 10],
  [15, 13],
];

myPixels.forEach((args) => {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
  ctx.fillRect(args[0], args[1], 1, 1);
});
```

```css
canvas {
  image-rendering: pixelated;
  width: 10em;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="cvs"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation using `ImageData` we draw 10 pixels at random locations

```js
const c = document.querySelector("#cvs")
const img = new ImageData(c.width, c.height)
const img_data = new Uint32Array(img.data.buffer)

var myPixels = []
for (var i=1; i<=10; i++) 
  myPixels.push({
    x: Math.floor(Math.random() * c.width), 
    y: Math.floor(Math.random() * c.height)
  })
myPixels.forEach((p) => img_data[p.y * c.width + p.x] = 68719411792)
c.getContext("2d").putImageData(img, 0, 0)
```

```css
canvas {
  image-rendering: pixelated;
  width: 10em;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="cvs" width=20 height=20></canvas>
```